# dynamic array created in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

How to fill a dynamically allocated 2D array? for example:

```
#define n 100
char **array;
array = new char*[n];
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    array[i] = new char[n];
}
```

How to fill this 2D array with `*` value?

Comment: You can always use a loop inside a loop.

Comment: you do not have a 2D array but an array of string, this is not the same thing

Comment: @bruno is right. array of string or vector of string.

Answer (score 1):

- Your code came very close to achieve what you wanted.
- Just like you wrote, `array[i]` is an `n` length character array.
- To write `'*'` to its `j`-th entry all you have to do is:

```
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        array[i][j] = '*';
    }
}
```

Comment: `'a'` is not `'*'`as expected by the OP, and why not using *memset* ?

Comment: @bruno I prefer a double nested loop, but of course there are other ways too ...

Comment: *memset* is faster, may be propose both ?

Comment: You must also warn the OP *array* is **not** a 2D array

Answer (score 1):

Both the answers you got so far are correct. You can see it as an 2D array or as an array of strings. You can store data on it char by char or directly writing a string. Maybe using constants instead of define would be a better practise.

```
const int n = 100;
char **array;
array = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * n);

bool storeString = true;

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    array[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * n);
    
    if(storeString)
        array[i] = "Im striiinging in the rain";
    
    else
        for(int j = 0; j < n-1; j++)
        {
            array[i][j] = '0';
        }
}
```

I'm using C type memory allocation but that shouldn't be an issue, I just don't remember how to do it precisely on C++ type, just   `import <cstdlib>`

Answer (score 0):

As @Bruno mentioned in comments, it is not 2D array but an array of strings.
You can directly store the string with 1 loop. Either assign string by using = operator, or use memset function.

```
    char **array;
    array = new char*[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        array[i] = "whatever";
    }
```